# Java: Creating a JSON response containing multiple values in a Restful Service

Tags: java, json, eclipse, rest, google-app-engine

I have implemented the following method in my Restful Web service in an Eclipse Java Project, which simply returns one value and is presented as a json response to the clients who access it. It works properly.

```
@GET
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
@Path("/getname/{userid}/")
public String GetName(@PathParam("userid") String userid) { 
    String name = "Earthling";
    return name ;
}
```

Now let's look at multiple values. I need to return 3 values separately in the same response **without creating a custom object for it**.

**As an example, I wrote this scenario in a C# Project of mine:**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/getname")]
public IHttpActionResult GetName(string userid) {
    String name = "Earthling";
    String extraValue = "1";
    Boolean anotherValue = false;
    return Ok(new {name , extraValue, anotherValue });
}
```

How do I write the above C# Example in Java and allow the method to return 3 objects (of different types) as a response in my Restful Web Service? Like I said, I don't want to create a separate object to encapsulate them.

***Tada! Question Time:***

1) How do I return multiple values (String, Boolean, etc) as a JSON Response in Java?

2) The Java Method I've written returns a String value (1st example). If I return 3 values how do I define the method? In C#, I can simply use IHttpActionResult and I don't have to explicitly specify the object type

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this in Java, you can make use of the `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` class.

Just wrap all the values that you want to return in the response inside a single class (for illustration, i am naming the class as "SampleResponse")

```
public class SampleResponse {
 String name = "Earthling";
 String extraValue = "1";
 Boolean anotherValue = false;
 // getter setter
```

}

And your method definition should be like

```
public Response GetName(@PathParam("userid") String userid) {
   return Response.ResponseBuilder.ok(new SampleResponse());}
```

That should do the job for you.

Comment: It gives me a error saying 'The type Response is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments < SampleResponse >'

Comment: I used javax.ws.rs.core as well

Comment: Can you post the stack trace here ?

Comment: My bad, use the Response without the typed parameters and to set the object in the response use the Response.ResponseBuilder.ok(object); (this is for a success response). I am editing my answer to reflect the right answer.